# get average number of count

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a `Shippers` table and a `Orders` table. To get the number of orders sent by each shipper, I use the following statement:

```
SELECT Shippers.ShipperName,COUNT(Orders.OrderID) AS NumberOfOrders FROM Orders
LEFT JOIN Shippers
ON Orders.ShipperID=Shippers.ShipperID
GROUP BY ShipperName;
```

It works fine. Based on the result of the above statement, how can I get the **average number** of orders sent by each shipper?

Answer (score 1):

You achieve this by using the AVG() function:

```
SELECT Shippers.ShipperName, AVG(Orders.OrderID) AS AvgNumberOfOrders 
FROM Orders
LEFT JOIN Shippers
ON Orders.ShipperID=Shippers.ShipperID
GROUP BY ShipperName;
```

More information: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_avg.asp

Answer (score 0):

Try with a subquery

```
SELECT myT.*, AVG(NumberOfOrders) FROM(

    SELECT Shippers.ShipperName,COUNT(Orders.OrderID) AS NumberOfOrders FROM Orders
    LEFT JOIN Shippers
    ON Orders.ShipperID=Shippers.ShipperID
    GROUP BY ShipperName;

) myT
```

Comment: so `myT` represents the result table from my query, right?

Comment: It's the alias of the table created from results of subselect. It's mandatory for all subselect (it could be with any name)

Answer (score 0):

One method is a subquery:

```
SELECT AVG(NumberOfOrders)
FROM (SELECT s.ShipperName, COUNT(o.OrderID) AS NumberOfOrders
      FROM Orders o LEFT JOIN
           Shippers s
           ON o.ShipperID = s.ShipperID
      GROUP BY s.ShipperName
     ) t;
```

However, a simpler way is to just do the division yourself:

```
SELECT COUNT(o.OrderID) / COUNT(DISTINCT s.ShipperName)
FROM Orders o LEFT JOIN
     Shippers s
     ON o.ShipperID = s.ShipperID;
```

Note:  Two reasonable assumptions are that each shipper has its own id and that all shippers have at least one order.  If so, you can simplify this to:

```
SELECT COUNT(o.OrderID) / COUNT(DISTINCT l.ShipperId)
FROM Orders o;
```